# Проблема с редактированием кода при отладке

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Отлаживаю динамическую библиотеку (DLL), хочу отредактировать код и продолжить, собственно открываю процесс через `Local Windows Debugger` , и пытаюсь изменить любой участок кода, в ответ получаю это :

```
-------- Edit and Continue build started --------

main.cc
c_game.cc
--------------------- Done ----------------------

Edit and Continue : An error occurred while applying code changes.
```

Не понимаю как это исправить, нашел ответы где советуют сбросить настройки VS, не помогло, Repair так же без результата

Comment: А там не пишется, что за ошибка? Проект собирается без предупреждений?

Comment: я так понимаю, вы пытаетесь редактировать код во время того, как длл загружена в память процесса. К сожалению в этом случае воспользоваться функцией edit and continue не получится из-за особенностей загрузки длл в память процесса. Для отладки длл вам необходимо будет завершать процесс, вносить правки, пересобирать длл и заново запускать процесс.

Comment: Ошибок вообще никаких нет

Comment: @goldstar_labs насколько я понял, эта функция создана специально чтобы не перезапускать каждый раз процесс

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в настройках проекта, точно сказать не могу, но полный сброс помог, теперь все отлично